# Dividing evens of a list by two

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
halveEvens :: [Int] -> [Int] 
halveEvens xs = [if xs == even then 'div' 2 xs | x<-xs]
```

Hey I'm trying to write down some code in haskell which will take the evens from a list and divide them by two. I am really new to this, so I am having some trouble. Is there anyone who could put me on the right track? I want to achieve this using list comprehension!

Comment: The "I want to achieve this using list comprehension" makes this seem like homework....  That being said, let me point out that in Haskell, `if` requires `then` and `else`, also you are using the full list `xs` on the left side of the `|` when you really need to use the element, and you should review the difference between ' and backticks, as well as the placement of operators created by using backticks.

Comment: You should perhaps have a helper function... Why do you need it with list comprehension?

Comment: You are close, just read about [list comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension) syntax, esp. how to write guards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `xs` is a list, [`even` is a function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:even) that checks if `Integral` is even.

To use functions like operators, you enclose it in back quotes like this : `` x `div` 2 ``.

```
halveEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halveEvens = map halveOneEven

halveOneEven :: Int -> Int
halveOneEven x = if (even x) then (x `div` 2) else x
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension with a guard after a comma:

```
halveEvens xs = [x `div` 2 | x<-xs, even x]
```

You could read it as a mathematical definition: take all `x` values from `xs` that are even, and collect the result of dividing them into a list. In `ghci` you can use `:t` to check the types and make them match (`xs` is of type `[Int]`, `x` is `Int`, and `even` is `(Integral a) => a -> Bool`).